# ZF2 file upload doesn't work

Tags: php, file-upload, zend-framework2

I try to upload a file with ZF2, but the file doesn't get uploaded. The form seems to be valid. Is there anything wrong with my code?

If I upload the image with php `move_uploaded_files`, everything work as expected.

**Form:**

```
class LogoUploadForm extends Form {

    public function init() {
        $this->add([
            'type' => 'File',
            'name' => 'logo',
            'attributes' => array(
                'id' => 'logo-input'
            ),
        ]);
    }

}
```

**InputFilter:**

```
class LogoInputFilter extends InputFilter {

    public function init() {
        $this->add([
            'name' => 'logo',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'File\RenameUpload',
                    'options' => [
                        'target' => './data/upload/',
                        'overwrite' => true,
                        'randomize' => true,
                        'use_upload_extension' => true,
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'File\MimeType',
                    'options' => [
                        'magicFile' => false, //Important: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6493
                        'mimeType' => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'File\UploadFile',
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'File\Size',
                    'options'   => [
                        'max' => '4MB'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class LogoController extends AbstractActionController  {
    public function uploadAction() {
        $form = $this->logoUploadForm;
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $form->setData(array_merge_recursive(
                $request->getPost()->toArray(),
                $request->getFiles()->toArray()
            ));

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                exit('valid');
            } else {
                exit('invalid');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting ? or put your code in `try` `catch` block.

Comment: Also paste validation error messages from the form (`$form->getMessages()`)

Comment: i don't get any error messages. my script exits with the message 'valid'. So everything seems to be ok, but the file didn't get uploaded...

Answer (score 0):

You should call in the view the prepare function before the form opentag function:

```
    $form->prepare();
    echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
```

The form will detect, at the moment you call the prepare function, the proper form encoding type to be used.

Comment: I call `$form->prepare()` in view before the open tag

Comment: Can you also post your action code and the view script?